# Web Service endpoint for plain XML with no namespace

Tags: xml, web-services, spring

I want to create an `Endpoint` for my webservice that will listen for plain XML objects which have no namespace and look like:

```
<?xml ....>
<xmlmessage>
   <item>
     <value> some value</value>
   </item>
</xmlmessage>
```

normally i have implemented `SOAP` endpoint which look like

```
    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "message", namespace = "http://test.namespace")
    @ResponsePayload
    public messageResponse getmessage(@RequestPayload message param) {
    //logic here
    }
```

But i believe that trying to achieve what I wrote at begging this way is impossible. Can anyone redirect me to somewhere? I can't find any suitable article writing how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is viable for you, but you could try to use Spring MVC instread of Spring WS for your webservice if you only need basic functionality.  Otherwise you might not be able to do it without a proper namespace

```
@Controller
public class MyEndPoint{


 @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.GET, value="/message")
    public @ResponseBody messageResponse getmessage(HttpServletRequest request) {

    ...Here you extract the text from the request, and parse the XML yourself....
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to have both `@Endpoint` and `@Controller` annotations?